# Jquery Dialog Box with overlay background

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I am using jquery dialog box abut not able to see the background overlay. code is below

$("#dialog").dialog();


I'm in a dialog

I am new to jquery, please help me out, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see overlay, you have to call dialog with `modal: true` parameter:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ modal: true });
```